# How to output the html for thumbnails in frontend also for webp version (without plugin)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use my own theme in Wordpress. How can I extend the output of the_thumbnail in functions.php so that the webp version of the image is also output?

If not possible: How can I change the_thumnail so that a  set including webp and jpg is output?

The pictures are basically already available in webp and jpg. No plugin is used for this. So my question deals exclusively with the output of the HTML part, which by default only contains the jpg/png version.

Comment: If the webp image is already in the media you could use wp_get_attachment_image_src() to get the image src and build your own <img> tag. If you want alt as well that will need some more work, I have some code ready (I use it alot!) if you want =]

Comment: just the original image (jpg/png) is stored in media

Comment: "The pictures are basically already available in webp and jpg", where are they available?
Without knowing where the webp is located or how webp/jpg is connected i can't help =/

Comment: The webp images are automatically generated via a script and are stored in the same directory as the originals. So if there are e.g. the pics example.jpg and example-500.jpg, there are also the pics example.webp and example-500.webp

Comment: oh ok, so you can use wp_get_attachment_image_src() and just replace .jpg with .webp

Comment: But with that I always have webp images and only ever in one size. the_thumbnail provides me with different image sizes (suitable for the device). I need a solution that continues to output the various sizes and also shows webp as an alternative for supporting browsers.

Comment: For that, the only option that comes to mind is the <picture> tag, check [Using WebP Images](https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/) and [HTML <picture> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)

Comment: True. But how can I force wordpress (via functions.php) to generate these picture-tags automatically instead of the given img-tags.